# SYBASE query with parameter in a store procedure

Tags: sql, sybase

In a SQL Server stored procedure, I can write like this:

```
begin
    declare 
    @sSQL       varchar(max),
    @cod1       varchar(10)

    set @sSQL='update myTable set col_name=''ERR'' where col_id=''' + @cod1 + '''';
    exec (@sSQL);
end;
```

How can I do the same with a Sybase stored procedure? I need to execute a SQL command with variables.

When I try to write the same code in SYBASE, I got a syntax error on `exec (@sSQL);`

Comment: Rather than using dynamic sql, why can't you just have
`UPDATE myTable SET col_name = 'ERR' WHERE col_id = @cod1;`

Comment: Mine was only an example. @cod1 could come from an input

Comment: It makes no difference, whether it is a parameter or a local variable

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? this info will help in determining valid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
SET @sSQL = 'UPDATE myTable SET col_name = ''ERR'' WHERE col_id = ''' + @cod1 + ''''

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @sSQL
```

As `exec()` for this purpose not exist in sybase, you can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as a fast solution.

Comment: I got the error: syntax error near IMMEDIATE.

Comment: you can try so EXECUTE(@sSQL) instead of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, should work fine in your case.